# How do I prioritise physical memory for a particular process?

Tags: 14.04, memory-usage

I have a process which is consuming roughly 13.5GB on a machine with 16GB running Ubuntu 14.04. The available memory according to System Monitor is 15.6GiB, of which 1.7GiB is reported as being used by other processes.

When I run my process, memory usage reaches ~85% and immediately goes to swap, crippling the process.

How can I make sure that this doesn't happen, and the process is given the highest memory priority? I don't care about CPU-priority as much, because the process only runs on a single core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is helpful

https://superuser.com/questions/243357/how-to-prevent-a-specific-program-from-swapping

If you really don't want to swap, get more RAM, or just `#swapoff -a` (not recomended, can turn your system unusable if you already have problems) on terminal.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578137/can-i-tell-linux-not-to-swap-out-a-particular-processes-memory